# infinite series: which test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

so, we recently started to learn about series, i feel like i'm confused a little and, i seem like i don't know how to start with this,i guess maybe it's either comparison test, or limit comparison test, can anyone explain to me how to solve it?

$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ n\tan\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series diverges, because for all $a \in [0,\frac {\pi}2)$, $\tan a \ge a$.

Therefore $n\tan\frac 1 n \ge n * \frac 1 n$, and latter is $1$.

We know that $\sum 1$ diverges,
therefore, $$\sum n\tan\frac 1 n$$ diverges.

As for what test it is, it is comparison test.